# Getting PyCharm to recognize __import__.py file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, importerror, python-import

When I use "from selenium import webdriver" on `pyCharm`, it throws up an `ImportError`. In the process of figuring out my issue and running `print  selenium.__file__`, it stated the path was "usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/selenium.pyc". It should, however, `connect __init__ file` instead.

the `__init__ files` exists - I checked.

I've tried making this a source folder on the `Project Structure` window in PyCharm's preferences to no avail.

So I removed `selenium.pyc` via the terminal with `sudo rm -rf selenium.pyc` hoping that it would default to the `__init__ file`, re-ran it again, and came to find that PyCharm attempted to import `selenium.py`. Deleting this file in addition removing `selenium.pyc` basically kills the entire module.

I'm fairly new at this and have been at this problem for 3 days, and will not stop till I figure this out. What else should I do? If you really don't want to answer this question, could you at least recommend me a book or website that would help me solve these problems?

P.s. I have a mac.

Comment: What happens if you run `from selenium import webdriver` from a python terminal? Might not be a pyCharm issue

Comment: Just got home from a long day at work - my apologies. It is correct from a python terminal (if i understand - opening the iTerm, typing python, and then using the import statements): /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/__init__.pyc

Comment: I haven't used pyCharm before, you might might consider trying to [clear its cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: i've tried that - didn't work. maybe its the way python is installed. However - code runner is the only IDE that recognizes selenium. Trying to figure out why that is and not iPython or PyCharm. And I would like to use PyCharm for the amazing autocomplete features.

Comment: It turned out to be a bug in the system. A new version of PyCharm (4.0) was just released this week and it eradicated the bug. Works perfectly!!